# Octave lsim not working, "unable to find function"

Tags: matlab, octave

Whenever I try to run the `lsim` command in Octave, I get

```
error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @is_real_matrix
```

Here's what I am trying to do:

```matlab
>> n=3*[2 125];
>> d=[1 9 45 125];
>> t=0:0.01:5;
>> x=3*ones(size(t));
>> y=lsim(n, d, x, t);
error: invalid function handle, unable to find function for @is_real_matrix
error: called from
    lsim at line 83 column 11
```

I've loaded in the control package and everything. Could someone tell me what's going on?

I am currently using Octave 6.4.0, and the version of `control` is 3.2.0.

Comment: Could you share more details?

Comment: please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .  in particular, if you type `help lsim`, which calling form are you attempting to use?  what are your x and t variables?

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, including the stack trace, which is very helpful in understanding what is going on. However, since `@is_real_matrix` is not an input, this might be an internal error, a bug. What versions of Octave and the Control package do you have? Did you try updating  to the latest versions? Did you search for this issue on the Octave bug tracker?

Comment: Yep, just updated.